# Importing CoAP.NET in Unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, coap

I've made a simpre CoAP server in Java, and now I need need to make a client in my android AR app made in Unity with ARFoundation.
I've added the ddl files of CoAP.NET (https://github.com/smeshlink/CoAP.NET) in the Asset folder, but in the console i get those errors:

> Assembly 'Library/ScriptAssemblies/Assembly-CSharp.dll' will not be loaded due to errors:
> Reference has errors 'CoAP.NET'.

> Assembly 'Assets/Code/CoAP.net/CoAP.NET.dll' will not be loaded due to errors:
> Unable to resolve reference 'Common.Logging.Core'. Is the assembly missing or incompatible with the current platform?
> Reference validation can be disabled in the Plugin Inspector.
> Unable to resolve reference 'Common.Logging'. Is the assembly missing or incompatible with the current platform?
> Reference validation can be disabled in the Plugin Inspector.

Searching online I think that the library is not compatible with Unity.
Is there another way to send CoAP requests using C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to import CoAP.NET, but in the end I was able to make CoAP requests using Californium in a Java native plugin that I imported in Unity.

Comment: That would have been my recommendation. Without unity I use Californium with Android now for a couple of years.